# Using mean to calculate most likely

Tags: r, probability

At a car hire service 50% of cars are returned on time. A sample of 20 car hires is studied. In order to calculate the probability all 20 cars are returned on time I use the binomial distribution :

```
dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5)
```

How can I calculate the mean to determine the most likely number of returned cars ? 
To calculate the mean I use :

```
mean(dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5))
```

which returns :

```
[1] 9.536743e-07
```

How can I then use the mean to calculate the most likely number of returned cars ?

Comment: `mean(dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5))` does not calculate the mean of the binomial distribution. `dbinom(x=20, size=20, prob=0.5)` calculates the probability of 20 successes out of 20 trials with a 0.5 probability of success, which is very small (namely, 9.54e-07). It returns a single number, so taking the mean of that returns the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `most likely number of returned cars` and the `mean number of returned cars` are not in general the same.

In particular, the former is constrained to be an integer; the latter is potentially continuous-valued.

The answer to the former comes from `dbinom`:

```
xx = 0:20
xx[which.max(dbinom(xx, size=20, prob=0.5))]
# [1] 10
```

If you wanted the mean, you just have to weight by `xx`:

```
sum(xx*dbinom(xx, size = 20, prob = .5))
# [1] 10
```

Of course the mean of a binomial variable is `prob * size`, so you need only select a value of `prob` for which this isn't an integer to see the difference:

```
prob = sqrt(2)/2
xx[which.max(dbinom(xx, size=20, prob=prob))]
# [1] 14
sum(xx*dbinom(xx, size = 20, prob = prob))
# [1] 14.14214
```

If you really insist on using `mean`, you probably mean to *simulate* the average of the binomial distribution, in which case you need to use `rbinom` instead:

```
mean(rbinom(1e6, size = 20, prob = .5))
# [1] 10.00235
```

Comment: as mean=np is the mean value not result of 20*.5 ?

Comment: @blue-sky 20*.5 = 10 ??

Comment: as n=20 and p=.5 the product of np is 10

Comment: @blue-sky sorry i miss your point. Can you re-read my answer again and see if that solves it?

Comment: I have computed same mean using np where you have used r code to compute. I just want to ensure that computing the mean as product of np is also correct ?

Comment: @blue-sky https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution if you're still unclear, I would ask at CrossValidated

Answer (score 1):

The expected value is E(X)=np, that is the most likely outcome.

The mode is:

1. floor of (n+1)p, if (n+1)p is 0 or a noninteger,
2. (n+1)p and (n+1)p-1, if (n+1)p is in {1,...,n}
3. n, if (n+1)p=n+1